# Need help with approach to a Electrostatics problem regarding finding potential of a configuration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, voltage

Two conducting planes, intersecting at right-angles to each other, are kept at a potential phi.
Calculate the potential at a point in space if the total charge on a plane of area(alpha) be Q.

I am studying electrostatics for the first time so might have a fundamental jumbled. But should i solve this using Method of Images, and what does the charge on the plane mean? should i superpose the electric potential solution of conducting planes with test charge and the potential due to the charge(Q) on the planes?

note - all potential here is electric potential

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are interested in the potential at some point $P = (d_1,d_2)$ as compared to the intersecting charged planes which we will call $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$. In this setup, $P$ is a shortest distance $d_1$ away from the plane $\Omega_1$ and so on. An easy way to set up this problem is by thinking about the following integral formulation for the potential

$$ V(d_1,d_2) = \int_{\Omega_1 \cup \: \Omega_2}  \frac{k \: dq}{r(d_1,d_2)} \text{ .} $$

Now we realize that if the charge distribution on the plane is constant, then it will be given by $$ \sigma = \dfrac{dq}{dA} = \frac{Q}{\alpha} = \text{ constant. }$$ We can then use the substitution

$$ V(d_1,d_2) = \int_{\Omega_1 \cup \: \Omega_2}  \frac{k\sigma \: dA}{r(d_1,d_2)}  $$

and split the integral as

$$ V(d_1,d_2) = \int_{\Omega_1 }  \frac{k\sigma \: dA}{r(d_1)} +  \int_{ \Omega_2}  \frac{k\sigma \: dA}{r(d_2)} \text{ .} $$

This shows that, yes, you can in fact superimpose the solutions of two lone planes to match this situation. The answer will not depend on the potential of a "test charge". If you wish, you can always substitute $\sigma = Q/\alpha$ as well.

Comment: Is the the phi potential on the conducting planes a red herring?

Comment: And also how does a simple conducting plane have a potential due to a test charge kept above it then? And why is that not applicable here?

Comment: @ShricharanArumugam the planes are each given a charge distribution. The potential $\Phi$ on the planes helps describe what it takes to put all those charges in a particular geometry. The fact that both planes have the same potential tells us that the charge distribution is the same across the entire union $\Omega_1 \cup \Omega_2$.